# How to bind by element name when control is inside a UserControl?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to bind the `Fill` property of a `Rectangle` to a property in the page's `DataContext` by using the element name, but because the `Rectangle` is in a `UserControl` the page is not found so binding does not occur.

Simplified example:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:Converters_Theme="using:ProjectName.Common.Converters"
    xmlns:CustomControls="using:ProjectName.CustomControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:ProjectName.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ViewModel="using:ProjectName.ViewModels"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="ProjectName.Views.TestPage"
    x:Name="pageName"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Converters_Theme:ThemeColorToSolidColorBrushConverter x:Key="ThemeColorToSolidColorBrushConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <!-- ... -->
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding DataContext.Theme.Color, Converter={StaticResource ThemeColorToSolidColorBrushConverter}, ElementName=pageName}" MinHeight="40" MinWidth="40" />
                <!-- ... -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Page.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:PageViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <CustomControls:Tab>
            <CustomControls:Tab.LeftContent>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemDataTemplate}" />
            </CustomControls:Tab.LeftContent>
            <CustomControls:Tab.RightContent>
                <!-- ... -->
            </CustomControls:Tab.RightContent>
        </CustomControls:Tab>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: I am not sure I got your question 100% but what is your DataContext object?

Comment: @Adil My `DataContext` is a view model with (among other things) a property named `Items` and a property named `Theme`.

Comment: The binding based on "ElementName" is not available anymore in winrt apps.
You must change the way your datas are structured, to store the value of "Color" inside each object of your "Items" collection

Comment: @Miiite You can bind on `ElementName`, it works fine when I use the binding on things which are not inside a custom UserControl.  It is just this case that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to accomplish it is to make your ViewModel a StaticResource, e.g. in App.xaml (may work in your Page.xaml):

```
<App.Resources>
    <ViewModel:PageViewModel x:Key="MyPageViewModel" />
</App.Resources>
```

And then reference to it in your Page.xaml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:Converters_Theme="using:ProjectName.Common.Converters"
    xmlns:CustomControls="using:ProjectName.CustomControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:ProjectName.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ViewModel="using:ProjectName.ViewModels"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="ProjectName.Views.TestPage"
    x:Name="pageName"
    DataContext="{StaticResource MyPageViewModel}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Converters_Theme:ThemeColorToSolidColorBrushConverter x:Key="ThemeColorToSolidColorBrushConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <!-- ... -->
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Theme.Color, Source={StaticResource MyPageViewModel}, Converter={StaticResource ThemeColorToSolidColorBrushConverter}}" MinHeight="40" MinWidth="40" />
                <!-- ... -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <CustomControls:Tab>
            <CustomControls:Tab.LeftContent>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemDataTemplate}" />
            </CustomControls:Tab.LeftContent>
            <CustomControls:Tab.RightContent>
                <!-- ... -->
            </CustomControls:Tab.RightContent>
        </CustomControls:Tab>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

To do it in much more cleaner way, I advise you to use ViewModelLocator as a static resource in app, which will properties to all ViewModels and make it StaticResource in App.xaml. It is much more cleaner way to instantiate one class in App.xaml than every ViewModel you have.

Comment: While this sounds like a nice option, the static requirement makes it unusable for me.